# How do I solve this kind of problem through pandas.cut()?

Tags: pandas

I have my data as

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,50,50,60],'B':[49,5,37,59],'C':[15,34,43,6],'D':[35,39,10,25]})
```

If I use cut this way

```
p = ['A','S','T','U','V','C','Z']
bins = [0,30,35,40,45,50,55,60]
data['A*'] = pd.cut(data.A,bins,labels=p)
print(data)
```

I get

```
    A   B   C   D  A*
0   3  49  15  35  A
1  50   5  34  39  V
2  50  37  43  10  V
3  60  59   6  25  Z
```

How would I cut it to get

```
    A   B   C   D  A*
0   3  49  15  35  3A
1  50   5  34  39  50V
2  50  37  43  10  50V
3  60  59   6  25  60Z
```

I tried this but doesn't work

```
for x in data.A:
    p = [str(x)+'A',str(x)+'S',str(x)+'T',str(x)+'U',str(x)+'V',str(x)+'C',str(x)+'Z']
bins = [0,30,35,40,45,50,55,60]
```

It gives me this

```
    A   B   C   D  A*
0   3  49  15  35  60A
1  50   5  34  39  60V
2  50  37  43  10  60V
3  60  59   6  25  60Z
```

Comment: I am totally excited with your question, really nice - data, expected output, what you try. Unfortunately in this times perfect questions like this are very rare...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert column `A` to strings and categoricals from `pd.cut` too and join together:

```
p = ['A','S','T','U','V','C','Z']
bins = [0,30,35,40,45,50,55,60]
data['A*'] = data.A.astype(str) + pd.cut(data.A,bins,labels=p).astype(str)
print(data)
    A   B   C   D   A*
0   3  49  15  35   3A
1  50   5  34  39  50V
2  50  37  43  10  50V
3  60  59   6  25  60Z
```

EDIT:

For processing all columns is possible use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str) + pd.cut(x,bins,labels=p).astype(str))
print(data)
     A    B    C    D
0   3A  49V  15A  35S
1  50V   5A  34S  39T
2  50V  37T  43U  10A
3  60Z  59Z   6A  25A
```

Comment: And is it possible to do the cut on the whole dataframe at once? Something like    data = data.astype(str) + pd.cut(data,bins,labels=p).astype(str)?????

Comment: It shows NAnan where theres a blank. I've been able to fillna((-1) in the main data but end up sorting only the nan side and I get  -1_.How do I get rid of the -1?

Comment: @fakeMake - What should be output if `data = pd.DataFrame({'A':[3,50,np.nan,60],'B':[49,5,37,np.nan]})` ?

Comment: Okay. I had a different data but I have sorted it though. I was replacing -1, rather than -1'. I'd forgotten they'd  been converted to strings. Your answer was correct as per the question I asked though. Thanks.